# Convertir XML a Objeto C#

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un `string`, en el cual guardo la serialización de un objeto a formato XML, quedando se la siguiente forma:

```
<miObjeto>
  <id>01</id>
  <Lista>
    <elemento>1</elemento>
    <elemento>2</elemento>
    <elemento>3</elemento>
  </Lista>
</miObjeto>
```

Ahora bien, lo que me gustaría es poder convertir ese `string` nuevamente a una instancia de un objeto de tipo `miObjecto`. Si me podrían ayudar se agradecería.

Nota: aquí se encuentra el método que uso para serializar a XML los objetos.

```
public static XElement ToXml(this object input, string element)
{
    if (input == null)
        return null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element))
        element = "object";
    element = XmlConvert.EncodeName(element);
    var ret = new XElement(element);

    if (input != null)
    {
        var type = input.GetType();
        var props = type.GetProperties();

        var elements = from prop in props
                       let name = XmlConvert.EncodeName(prop.Name)
                       let val = prop.GetValue(input, null)
                       let value = prop.PropertyType.IsSimpleType()
                            ? new XElement(name, val)
                            : val.ToXml(name)
                       where value != null
                       select value;
        ret.Add(elements);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta [repuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10518657/4092887) o consulta: `deserialize xml to object c#`.

Comment: Aca un link que te puede ayudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xm:l-to-object

Comment: Nota que tu XML está mal formado, final debería cerrar con `"...</miObjeto>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Lista")]
    public class Lista {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="elemento")]
        public List<string> Elemento { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="miObjeto")]
    public class MiObjeto {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Lista")]
        public Lista Lista { get; set; }
    }

}
```

y despues

```
string elXML = @"<miObjeto>
  <id>01</id>
  <Lista>
    <elemento>1</elemento>
    <elemento>2</elemento>
    <elemento>3</elemento>
  </Lista>
</miObjeto>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MiObjeto ));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(elXML))
{
    MiObjeto result = (MiObjeto ) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Por cierto, justo para tu primer comentario revisa [¿Es legítimo pedir reputaciones?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344/es-leg%C3%ADtimo-pedir-reputaciones)

Comment: Ok, ¿pero que pasa cuando el que pregunta, te dice que resolvió su problema con tu respuesta y no te da palomita? Eso no me parece que este correcto y te repito pensé que eras la persona que pregunto.

Comment: Justo en esa pregunta se desata la discusión, si lees todos los comentarios y respuestas, te podrás dar cuenta de las opiniones ahí expresadas

Comment: Pues si lo leí pero hablan del Dale +1, nunca de la palomita, que me parece muy distinto. Pero creo que daré fin a esto.

Comment: @Flxtr abrahamhs está en lo cierto. Si bien pedir reputación en comentarios se ve mal, pedir que pueda marcar la respuesta como aceptada no lo es, principalmente si el(la) autor(a) original es un nuevo usuario, es la única respuesta publicada sin borrar y parece resolver el problema. Este comentario debería tener connotación educacional p.e. "Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que más te ayudó. Para más información, revisar <enlace>" en lugar de solicitar que la publicación actual se acepte.