# ¿Cómo hacer EagerLoading en web api asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Buenas comunidad, quería consultarles, cómo podría hacer eagerloading en una aplicación web api. Lo hice en una aplicación windows forms normal, pero ahora quiero hacer un api consumible, sin embargo, siempre me tira el siguiente error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Additional information: Se han producido uno o varios errores.

mi controlador se ve así:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        using (context)
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var Expediente = context.Expediente.AsNoTracking().Include(x=>x.Documento.Select(a=>a.Archivo)).ToList();


            if (Expediente != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Expediente);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No se encontraron expedientes.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Y como lo consumo se ve así:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54585/") };
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Expedientes").Result;
        var emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>>().Result;
```

Cuando llega a la línea:

```
var emp = ....
```

me arroja el error. Si verifico linea por linea, me manda al OK no al error entonces no entiendo por qué.

Comment: El servicio web te retorna un json o un xml?

Comment: Me retorna un XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReadAsAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh944541(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) convierte la respuesta http al tipo `T` especificado, en tu caso `IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>`. El problema esta en que `Content` contiene un string, no un objeto de ese tipo por lo que la conversión no puede ser posible y tampoco posee un Formateador de XML a objeto para convertir el string al tipo `IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>`.

Tendras que obtener la respuesta como `string`, que seria el XML, y [convertir el XML manualmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50790/convertir-xml-a-objeto-c) utilizando [`XDocument.Parse(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) al tipo que tu esperas. Para leer el `string` del `Content`, utiliza el método [`ReadAsStringAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh551731(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
//...
string xml = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// convertir doc a IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>
//...
```

Si la respuesta es JSON, entonces utiliza `JsonConvert` de 
 [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para convertirlo al objeto que deseas:

```
//...
string json= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
var result = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>>(json);
//...
```

Comment: No pude hacer la conversión de doc a ExpedientePOCO, cómo debería de ser? intenté IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO> exp; exp = doc;

Comment: En mi respuesta mencione que tienes que hacerla manualmente. Tendras que recorer el XML utilizando el objeto XDocument y asi construir el objeto.

Comment: Jejeje soy nuevo en esto web así que no sé si podrías explicar un poco más en profundidad jejeje

Comment: E intenté lo que me pusiste y me sale esto: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Los datos del nivel de raíz no son válidos. línea 1, posición 1.

Comment: E intenté lo que me pusiste y me sale esto: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Los datos del nivel de raíz no son válidos. línea 1, posición 1.

revisé bien y en la línea de string xml = ... trae un error que dice:
type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; vharset=utf-8'.

Comment: `type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json`. Habia dicho que era XML la respuesta cuando en realidad es JSON

Comment: jejeje me tiraba xml no sé qué pasó, en el navegador tira xml

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta. Dale una mirada.